# Is there a more current way to fix the error encountered when parsing a DateTime value in the XML?

Tags: c#, rss, syndication

As you can see in this question 
[Problems Reading RSS with C# and .net 3.5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/210375/problems-reading-rss-with-c-and-net-3-5) 
There is a problem when trying to read some Rss Feeds that express their date differently.

I have tried the workaround posted there but I am not that experienced and I am trying it on Windows Phone 7.  My main difficulty is that XmlTextReader seems to be inaccessible.
So I was wondering if anyone could help me use XmlReader instead or if anyone knows a new workaround for this problem.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to use System.Xml.Linq? I even saw a example application (RSS Reader ;p) for windows phone 7.

http://dotnet.dzone.com/articles/building-rss-reader-windows-0  ?

Comment: Thanks for the link. I'll check it out.

Comment: Thanks for the link but that app suffers from the same error mine does.  An error was encountered when parsing a DateTime value in the XML.  I posted a link to a possible workaround but I can't quite get it to work for me.  You wouldn't happen to know how to apply it to that app you posted would you?

Comment: @Izzy Try sth like this: var notes = from note in rss select new { title = note.Attribute("title").Value, date = new DateTime(note.Attribute("date")) };

Comment: I'm not really sure about DateTime constructor and names of attributes but there should be some sort of clue ;-) [use System.Xml.Linq]