# Remove Html tags from RSS feed element

Tags: c#, rss, xmlreader

I am reading news feed that is corrupted sometimes when element contains html tags.
It throw this exception:

> [ Unexpected node type Element. ReadElementString method can only be
>   called on elements with simple or empty content.]

**XML Sample** :

```
<rss xmlns:atom="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom" version="2.0">
  <channel>
    <title>test xml feed</title>
    <atom:link href="http://www.newssite.com" rel="self" type="application/rss+xml"/>
    <description>test</description>
    <item>
      <title>
        Title followed by html tags
        <br/>
      </title>
      <link>
        http://www.newssite.com
      </link>
      <description>
        Description Data
      </description>
      <pubDate>Mon, 14 Jan 2013 21:20:00 +0400</pubDate>
      <category>Cat1</category>
    </item>
  </channel>
</rss>
```

**Code Sample** :

```
static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            XmlReader reader = new XmlTextReader(@"d:\test.xml");
            SyndicationFeed feed = SyndicationFeed.Load(reader);
        }
    }
```

I tried this [Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/210375/problems-reading-rss-with-c-sharp-and-net-3-5/2724742#2724742) for another xml date format issue and it was working perfectly. 
when i use it solve html tags it doesn't work and still throw exception.

Answer (score 0):

Parse the feed with the Html Agility Pack

On codeplex: http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/

Comment: HAP read files from file system only. i need read xml over internet.

Comment: if you look at the test called StackOveflow @ http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/view/99964#1096647. It reads from a webrequest...